# Is my loading icon bug a Xamarin Forms issue or my Code-Behind Issue

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I thought that my bug was a Xamarin Forms issue because there was no bug in XF3.4, but it appeared after I upgraded to XF4.4.

Just to make sure, I want to show you guys the code. I have a XAML page with the loading icon:

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding Loading}"
                   IsVisible="{Binding Loading}"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2">
    <ActivityIndicator.Color>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="#2499CE" WinPhone="#2499CE" />
    </ActivityIndicator.Color>
</ActivityIndicator>
```

The "Loading" boolean is binded in the page model here:

```
public class MyLoginWebPageModel : BasePageModel
{
    private BrowserOptions _options;
    private Action<BrowserResult> _trySetResult;
    private BrowserResult _result = new BrowserResult() { ResultType = BrowserResultType.UserCancel };
    private Boolean _navPopped = false;

    public string StartUrl { get; private set; }

    public bool Loading { get; set; } = false;    // RIGHT HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    public OidcLoginWebPageModel(ICoreDataRepository repository, ILoginProvider loginProvider, ICache cache, IEventTrace trace, IUsageTimer usageTimer, IPlatform platform)
            : base(loginProvider, cache, trace, usageTimer, platform){}

    public override void Init(object initData)
    {
        base.Init(initData);
        Tuple<BrowserOptions, Action<BrowserResult>> initObject = initData as Tuple<BrowserOptions, Action<BrowserResult>>;
        _options = initObject.Item1;
        _trySetResult = initObject.Item2;
        StartUrl = _options.StartUrl;
    }

    protected override void OnPageWasPopped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPageWasPopped(sender, e);
        _trySetResult(_result);
    }

    internal async Task OnBrowserNavigated(object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loading = false;
        if (!(sender is WebView browser))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Sender is not of type WebView");
        }
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(e.Url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Uri creation failed for: {e.Url}");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.EndUrl))
        {
            if (uri.LocalPath.ToLowerInvariant() == "/account/logout")
            {
                _result = new BrowserResult() { ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success };
                if (!_navPopped)
                {
                    _navPopped = true;
                    await PopPageModel();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal async Task OnBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        Loading = true;
        if (!(sender is WebView browser))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Sender is not of type WebView");
        }
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(e.Url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri))
        {
            throw new Exception($"Uri creation failed for: {e.Url}");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.EndUrl) == false)
        {
            if (uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_options.EndUrl))
            {
                _result = new BrowserResult() { ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success, Response = uri.Fragment.Substring(1) };
                e.Cancel = true;
                if (!_navPopped)
                {
                    _navPopped = true;
                    Loading = false;
                    await PopPageModel();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything in here that would indicate a loading icon not disappearing at all?

Thanks!

edit: So this is what I'm thinking I need to do.

First I change my boolean situation

```
private bool Loading = false;
public bool currentlyLoading
{
    get { return Loading; }
    set 
    { 
        currentlyLoading = Loading;
        onPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Then in the same file I implement the onPropertyChanged() function to.. let the Bindable property in my xaml file know that the property has changed?

Is this a good implementation?

```
// Option 1
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

// Option 2
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: `public bool Loading { get; set; } = false;` why you doing it like this?

Comment: @Jason it's not in the specific file I posted on here, but it is used throughout the rest of our program

Comment: @Blu That's how it was implemented when I started working with a team on this app

Comment: if `MyLoginWebPageModel` does not implement INPC, it needs to, and `Loading` needs to raise a `PropertyChanged` event

Comment: @Jason soin the MyLoginWebPageModel Constructor, I need to add in a parameter for INotifyPropertyChanged and everytime loading is changed, it has to raise the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: No.  INPC has nothing to do with the class constructor.  If you don't know how to use INPC, please stop and read the docs.  It is incredibly well documented.

Comment: Does the `BasePageModel` implement INotifyPropertyChanged? If so that will simplify things.

Comment: @Andrew Oh! It looks like it does, should have thought to look there

Comment: @Jason So I'm reading up on the Docs, and it seems like I need to do something like this:"
 private bool Loading = false;
        public bool currentlyLoading
        {
            get { return Loading; }
            set 
            { 
                currentlyLoading = Loading;
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }, 
now do I have to implement my own OnPropertyChanged()?

Comment: not if the base class already does

Comment: Take a look at some of the other classes in the project that inheriate from `BasePageModel`. You'll probably find where a property is already doing some kind of PropertyChanged. A call like `SetProperty(ref privateVar, value)` is common. If you need help, show us the base class.

Comment: I made edits, can you guys check them out? @Andrew

Comment: not quite - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

your class (or it's base class) needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Then your `Loading` property would look something like this

```
private bool loading = false;

public bool Loading
{
    get { return loading; }
    set 
    { 
        loading = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: By implementing INotifyPropertyChanged do you mean just having this line in my base class? "public class BasePageModel : FreshBasePageModel, INotifyPropertyChanged" Because that's already there. Do I need it in my class instead? Also what would value be, where is that implemented? And lastly which of the two OnPropertyChanged() methods in my edit should I put in my class? Thanks!

Comment: Everything you need to know is in the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Ok, that doc doesn't tell me if I need the `: INotifyPropertyChanged` after my base class and/or webpage class, can you let me know that one? I'm guessing I don't need it in the webpage class since it inherits from BasePage?

Comment: Please take the time to read a C# book.  You seem to be hung up on some basic concepts.  `value` is a C# keyword that is used in property setters.  Like someone else suggested, looking at how another page/model in the same project uses INPC would probably be a good idea.  We don't know all the details of your implementation so we can't give you specific advice.  I would imagine that `OnPropertyChanged` is already in your base class so you should not have to re-implement it.

Comment: Reading up on inheritance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance will help you understand that.

You mentioned FreshBasePageModel, is that FreshMVVM? If you are using an MVVM framework, you should checkout the frameworks docs.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is best. But it would be good if you move your property changed logic to `BasePageModel`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
private bool _loading { get; set; }
public bool Loading { get {return _loading; } set{value = _loading } }
```

And in your **OnBrowserNavigating**:

```
internal async Task OnBrowserNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    Loading = true;
    if (!(sender is WebView browser))
    {
        Loading = false;
        throw new Exception($"Sender is not of type WebView");
    }
    if (!Uri.TryCreate(e.Url, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri))
    {
        Loading = false;
        throw new Exception($"Uri creation failed for: {e.Url}");
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_options.EndUrl) == false)  //IF THE CONDITION OVER HERE & FOR INNER IF CONDITIONS FAILS, LOADER WASNT SET TO FALSE 
    {
        if (uri.AbsoluteUri.StartsWith(_options.EndUrl))
        {
            _result = new BrowserResult() { ResultType = BrowserResultType.Success, Response = uri.Fragment.Substring(1) };
            e.Cancel = true;
            if (!_navPopped)
            {
                _navPopped = true;
                Loading = false;
                await PopPageModel();
            }
        }
    }
    Loading = false;
}
```

Comment: this appears to be the same code, with just a minor change to the Loading property.

Comment: You just added comments.  There is no functional difference I can see between this and what the OP posted.  You also don't need to post all of the code if you are making changes to two lines.  And finally, you should explain what you changed and why you think it will fix the problem.

Comment: @Jason check updated code, refresh it, i already added comments n changd code

Comment: There's a popular quote: "Less Is More". 

Please use **Only** the needed code to go along your solution description, if you only changed 2 lines of code, you don't need to repost the entire code from the question.

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais read n check code, changes are more, he must have CHECK IT CAREFULLY before down voting

Comment: @Blu i seriously don't think you understood what i meant, i did saw your change, and again, you only changed 2 lines of code. i'm not going to respond anymore, instead, i'm going to propose an edit to your anwser.

Comment: i did an edit. accept if you want, for example: OnBrowserNavigated wasn't changed but you still added that code in your Awnser.